# Toggle and height adjust onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click on a button that makes the size of the container the button is in, become taller once the button is clicked.
But it is not working

the code is:

**HTML**

```
  <div id="dynamicInput" class="dynamicInput">

    <form name="new_addon" id="new_addon" method="post">

     <input type="text" id="Product_name" name="Product_name" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
     <input type="number" id="addon_price" name="addon_price" value="" placeholder="Additional Costs" maxlength="30" required>
     <!--Add add-ons to product button -->
     <input type="button" id="add_prod" name="add_prod" value="Add Option " >
     <input type="button" id="new" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

    </form> 
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
   $(document).ready(function (){
      $("#add_prod").on("click", function (){
        if ($(".dynamicInput").height() == 200) {
           $(".dynamicInput").animate(
               {height: "300px"});
           }
        else if ($(".dynamicInput").height() == 300) {
           $(".dynamicInput").animate({height: "200px"});
           }
        });
    });
```

Where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats work, you should `position:absolute` in your div

```
 <div id="dynamicInput" class="dynamicInput" style="position:absolute;height:200px;background-color:red;" >
```

result : https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/c9vsgauu/

Comment: Thank you. Turns out it was my css stoping it from working :s

Answer (score 0):

try  `#dynamicInput` instead on `.dynamicInput`

Comment: Ive tired both, neither works. i am really confused at this point.